# Wifi driver of lenovo thinkbook 15-IML

Tags: drivers, lenovo

I have purchased new laptop lenovo thinkbook 15-IML and i have decided to move away from windows. So, i installed ubuntu 20.04 but since this is my first experience i am having trouble with setting up the device to use it.
And the most important thing is to install wifi drivers. I need help in this regard. And also if anyone has prepared a setup guide than please also do share it.

**Command : lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list**

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:c82f]
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:c02f]
03:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS522A PCI Express Card Reader [10ec:522a] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Lenovo RTS522A PCI Express Card Reader [17aa:3832]
0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
3: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
```

**Command : lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; dmesg | grep rtw; dkms status**

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:c82f]
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:c02f]
03:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS522A PCI Express Card Reader [10ec:522a] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Lenovo RTS522A PCI Express Card Reader [17aa:3832]
rtlwifi-new, 0.6, 5.4.0-33-generic, x86_64: installed
```

**Command : dmesg | grep rtw**

```
 817.832946] rtw_core: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel. [ 817.833028] rtw_core: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel –
```

**Command : sudo mokutil --sb-state**

```
SecureBoot disabled
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: @Pilot6 i have updated the question.

Comment: OK, I made a typo. It is `sudo mokutil --sb-state`.

Comment: Hm, it looks like there is some bug in the driver, support of rtl8821ce was added 6 days ago. I can't help with that.

Comment: can you help me setup the finger print reader?

Comment: Most likely the fingerprint reader is not supported. They are rarely supported with new hardware.

Comment: well that's disappointing as it is my first experience with ubuntu.

Comment: This hardware is not good for Ubuntu yet.

Comment: but here in this document thinkbook 15 is certified for ubuntu.
https://certification.ubuntu.com/hardware/201910-27453

Comment: This is a completely different laptop. "thinkbook 15" doesn't mean much. Your laptop has a different wireless device and a different touchpad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a RTL8822CE wireless device, that is not supported by Ubuntu kernel yet. So you need to install a driver.

Connect to the internet using a cable or a phone and run in a terminal.

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install git dkms
git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtw88.git
sudo dkms add ./rtw88
sudo dkms install rtlwifi-new/0.6
```

Reboot and disable Secure Boot in BIOS.

Wifi should start working.

Comment: i have tried this but still the wifi is not appearing.

Comment: Were there any errors? Please add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; dmesg | grep rtw; dkms status` TO YOUR QUESTION.

Comment: edited the original question

Comment: Did you disable Secure Boot?

Comment: yes i did disable the secure boot

Comment: What does `sudo modprobe rtw_8821ce` show?

Comment: it shows nothing

Comment: And does `dmesg | grep rtw` show anything?

Comment: here is the output:

[  817.832946] rtw_core: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
[  817.833028] rtw_core: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel

Comment: Please add the full output to the question. It looks like secure boot is on.

Comment: i can not see your comments here anymore

Comment: What does `-b` option in git command mean?

Comment: It means "branch"